# How to write div class attribute BeaufitulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

i know to write new tag like this using python BeautifulSoup :

```
# create new_div
 new_div = soup.new_tag("div", id="description", style="float:left")
# insert it into the document
 soup.body.append(new_div)
```

but i got error when adding class attribute i got invalid syntax :

> new_div = soup.new_tag("div", class="description", style="float:left")
>                                         ^ SyntaxError: invalid syntax

How is the right way to add class attribute when creating new tag ?

thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [python beautifulsoup new\_tag: assign class as an attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23042963/python-beautifulsoup-new-tag-assign-class-as-an-attribute)

Answer (score 1):

i am sorry i got this to write by finding the others ref. [on stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23042963/python-beautifulsoup-new-tag-assign-class-as-an-attribute)

> new_div = soup.new_tag("div", style="float:left",
>   **{'class':'classname'})